# Find the tangent plane of the given function that is parallel to another plane

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-derivative

I've come across a problem that I cannot finalize.

*Problem:* In which points the tangent plane of the function

$$ f(x,y) = 5 + \frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{9} $$

is parallel to the plane given by the equation:

$$ z = x + 2y \ ? $$

I can compute the partial differentiations:

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}' = \frac{x}{8}, $$
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}' = \frac{2y}{9}, $$

so that the tangent plane has equation $$ z = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(x, x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(y, y_0)(y-y_0) + z_0. $$

That gives us the tangent plane:

$$ z = \frac{-9 x_0^2 - 16 y_0^2 + 720}{144} + \frac{x x_0}{8} + \frac{2 y y_0}{9} $$

I cannot see how can I find the point where the tangent plane is parallel to $z$?

Thank you for any clue.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by $ f(x,y)^\prime = \frac{8}{x} + \frac{2y}{9}$. You should be able to identify $f^\prime(x,y)$ with a vector. This is not the case with what you wrote.

Comment: Hint: The planes parallel to $z = x+2y$ are described by $z=x+2y+C$ for each real number $C$. So find the $x_0$ and $y_0$ values that make your equation match that.

Comment: When we take the derivative to get the tangent line to a single-variable function it gives us a function that is only parallel to it, because we lose the information in the constant term. The same is true of tangent planes in the multi-variable situation so this will simplify your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the hints and a couple of hours, I was finally able to figure it out.

With the tangent plane equation, we just need to look for the "linear combination" of the plane, meaning:

$$ z = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(x,x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(y,y_0)(y-y_0) + z_0 $$

needs to match the coeficient of the normal vector given by the paralel plane $$ z = x + 2y$$ which has the normal vector $(1,2,-1)^T$.

That gives us the following equations:
$$ \frac{x_0}{8} = 1$$
$$ \frac{2y_0}{9} = 2$$

which give us solutions: $x_0 = 8, y_0 = 9$. After the substitution we get the following formula:

$$
x + 2y - 18 - z + z_0 = 0
$$

Value of $z_0$ can be obtained from the assignment formula, ergo:

$$
z_0 = 5 + \frac{x_0^2}{16} + \frac{y_0^2}{9},
$$

$$
z_0 = 5 + \frac{64}{16} + \frac{81}{9},
$$

$$
z_0 = 5 + 4 + 9,
$$

$$
z_0 = 13.
$$

The desired tangent plane has the following formula:
$$ z = x + 2y - 8. $$

Thanks for all your comments.